# Python OR'ing arrays together

Tags: python

Is there an easier way of doing:

```
cd = [False,False,True]
ca = [False,False,False]
cp = [False,True,True]

ab[0] = cd[0] or ca[0] or cp[0]
ab[1] = cd[1] or ca[1] or cp[1]
ab[2] = cd[2] or ca[2] or cp[2]
```

to get `[False,True,True]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ab = [any(x) for x in zip(cd, ca, cp)]
```

Comment: can you explain that to me? It looks complex

Comment: Both [any()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) and [zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) are standard python functions, [documented here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
ab = [cd[x] or ca[x] or cp[x] for x in range(len(cd))]
```

Comment: `cd.count()` is not valid python?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `sum(...)` on an iterable of `bool`s will give you the number of `True`s, I assume that's what he was trying to do with `count` (though I didn't see it, he edited too fast).

Comment: @agf actually, I just wasn't awake yet and was using count() to get list length . . . too much PHP lately . . .

Comment: @agf You're talking about `[bool(sum(x)) for x in zip(cd, ca, cp)]`
--> `[False, True, True]` right?, but ernie did something like `range(cd.count())` :)